# Convert gridded data in a list to a data frame

Tags: r, interpolation

I have some xyz data (Time, Depth, and Temperature) I interpolated using akima, resulting in a list of length 3. I'm trying to figure out how to convert this into a data frame with x, y, and z columns.

```
str(df1_interp)
List of 3
 $ x: num [1:40] 5 5.15 5.31 5.46 5.62 ...
 $ y: num [1:40] 0 0.667 1.333 2 2.667 ...
 $ z: num [1:40, 1:40] 24.4 25 25.5 26 26.6 ...
```

I've tried pivot_longer, gather, and grid.to.xyz to no avail.

Comment: `as.data.frame(df1_interp)`?

Comment: I tried that, it results in a data frame with x, y and 40 z columns

Comment: yeah sure that's normal, because the `z` object in your list is a 40x40 matrix, what do you expect?

Comment: i need a data frame with one x, one y, and one z column

Comment: In [`akima::interp` documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/akima/akima.pdf) we can read "If input is SpatialPointsDataFrame a SpatialPixelssDataFrame is returned", that might be a hint.

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to convert to a raster:

```
    xyz_raster <- raster(matrix(akima.li$z, ncol = ncols, nrow = nrows),
    xmn = min(akima.li$x), xmx = max(akima.li$x),
    ymn = min(akima.li$y), ymx = max(akima.li$y))
```